# Testing factory and beforemethod

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to simplify my framework a little bit more. The current solution works, but it does cause some code duplication for me and some other issues that might come down the road.

```
public class Browsers {

  private String Browser;
  private String Windows;
  private String Ver;

  protected WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeTest
  public void BeforeMethod() {

    DriverFactory driverfactory = new DriverFactory();
    driver = driverfactory.createdriver(Browser);
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void AfterMethod() {}

  public Browsers(String Browser, String Windows, String Ver) {
    this.Browser = Browser;
    this.Windows = Windows;
    this.Ver = Ver;

  }


  @DataProvider
  public static Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
    return new Object[][] {{"FF", "WIndows", "10"}, {"Chrome", "Windows", "10"}};
  }

}


public class DriverFactory {

  private WebDriver driver;

  public WebDriver createdriver(String Browser) {
    if (Browser.contains("FF")) {

      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    else {
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    return driver;
  }


}


public class LoginTests extends Browsers {


  @Factory(dataProvider = "dataProviderMethod")
  public LoginTests(String Browser, String Windows, String Ver) {
    super(Browser, Windows, Ver);
  }


  @Test
  public void LoginValid() {

  }

  @Test
  public void LoginInvalid() {

  }


}
```

**Problem**

Currently, I'm able to run tests when I create a factory on each of the test classes.

I have to write a constructor to all the test classes that I create. Which causes me some code duplication. When I have 100 tests then it will be quite a lot. Is it possible to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, calling your super class "Browsers" is wrong, because it doesn't have anything to do with browsers. It is probably a TestBase class, if your Test extends it.
- You don't have to have duplicates and you don't have to have a constructor in your base class. Tests doesn't care about what browser it is executed on, so you should handle this information in TestBase class (currently Browsers). Personally I handle it in configuration/properties file. In that case I can switch easily and modify values from continuous integration server (i.e TeamCity).